# Adding a Custom Marker in Flutter with MapBox plugin

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-marker

So I'm currently working on a feature that uses MapBox package/plugin to display a Map on my app.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

So far from what I've seen in Flutter the `addSymbol` method only allows you to add images and text.

Does anyone know how to create a marker like the ones showed in the image? Is there any support for this?

Comment: Please share your current code

Comment: You can find everything I am using [here](https://github.com/tobrun/flutter-mapbox-gl/blob/master/example/lib/place_symbol.dart).